# Analysing an integer problem

Tags: calculus

I am trying to reverse analysis a -hopefully- simple function found in a software. I know the function is extremely fast (so it should be simple operation, no cryptography involved).

However I am lacking tools and methods to make any progress. How would one build a function which from the following input parameters (tuples of 32bits unsigned int) generate the following output (single 32bits unsigned int):

```
(10540,10786,443434,444390,466552,466805,506715,507174)       -> 3739768442
(42590,43848,3492103,3494653,3673616,3675704,3973645,3976278) -> 3658558629
(24459,25144,3503497,3504299,3637225,3638009,3860072,3860864) -> 2696452552
(3292,3351,52562,53048,55544,56241,61612,61680)               -> 1934023562
(9601,9945,382312,382590,395960,396331,419144,419254)         -> 1691229866
(39187,40173,4152379,4154388,4349934,4350838,4686282,4687198) ->  628066682
(3655,3740,31558,31588,32652,32768,34376,34490)               ->  500378360
(3208,3246,13601,13708,14112,14219,14838,14947)               ->  498003242
(7042,7205,161682,162051,168533,168841,179599,179930)         ->   44646691
```

Comment: Assume the result is a linear combination of the values and solve with linear algebra?

Comment: @JohnMcGee, that's a good idea, just make sure that when you do the solving, you do it with java BigInt types (or equivalent), or else a computer algebra system, so that you don't throw away the *low order* bits. Those are the bits you are interested in.